# Building HTML links based on user input with PHP

Tags: php, html, file

I am wanting to be able to create links that show up on the `links.html` page based on user submissions.

The links would follow this format `<a href="URL">TITLE</a>`, so quite simplistic.

Users will submit data via this form:

```html
<form action="links.php" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder= "URL:" name="url" required><br>
<input type="text" placeholder= "Title:" name="title" required><br>
<input type="submit">
```

And the PHP I'm using is

```
<?php
$url = $_POST["url"];
$title = $_POST["title"];
$text = "<a href="".$url.">".$title."</a> <br> \n"
$file = fopen("./data/links.html","a+ \n");
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file);
?>
```

I know that the issue lies with building the `".$url."` part as there are also speech marks. How would you get around this given that the URL requires the `"URL"` format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a parse error.

Comment: your `fopen()` failed also.

Comment: Allowing users to write to files is not a good idea, nothing stopping a user entering `<script>window.location = 'hxxp://evil.com'</script>` in the form.

Comment: I know, it's being used internally and the submissions of each user will be traceable and held for review. I set that up with a generic form response to begin with @LawrenceCherone

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: `$text = "<a href="".$url.">".$title."</a> <br> \n"` there; no closure. Or was that just a bad paste?

Comment: Do you know see Stack's syntax highlighting being thrown off? I asked if that was a bad paste, but I didn't hear anything back and some may think it's ok, which it isn't.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As long as the $text string is in double quotes, you can do this:

```
$text = "<a href='{$url}'>{$title}</a> <br> \n";
```

Comment: Great, thank you :) Issue with `data/URL.com` it adds that to the site path and doesn't open the URL

Comment: UPDATE: FIXED IT

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add the proper escape slashes for the quoting issue

```
$text = "<a href="".$url.">".$title."</a> <br> \n";
```

becomes

```
$text = "<a href=\"".$url."\">".$title."</a> <br> \n";
```

Or you could mix single and double quotes and not use escapes -

```
$text = "<a href='".$url."'>".$title."</a> <br> \n";
```